# Is the fingerprint scanner of HP laptops such as the ProBook 430 G2 simply incompatible with current Windows versions?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, fingerprint, sensors, windows-hello

I recently bought a refurbished HP ProBook 430 G2 in Japan. It feels new and I'm very happy with it.

I believe this model was originally sold with Windows 8 or 8.1 but it had a fresh install of Windows 10 on it when I bought it.

The laptop seems to have a fingerprint scanner below the keyboard, to the right of trackpad.

It doesn't seem to do anything. I can't find it listed in Device Manager. I can find lots of people asking similar questions on various forums but without adequate answers.

I have updated Windows 10 and updated all drivers from the HP website. I have specifically downloaded and run every version of the fingerprint scanner from HP's site that have links posted in the answers in the forums I found on this topic.

Under Sign-in Options / Windows Hello Fingerprint it says "This option is currently unavailable - click to learn more". Clicking does not lead to any solutions though.

My best theory is that Windows Hello is new and requires a specific kind of fingerprint scanner driver that is either not compatible with the sensor hardware on this laptop, or which has not had a Hello-compatible driver released for some reason.

My second theory is that perhaps my laptop has a "blank" where the fingerprint sensor would be and that it was optional and my laptop never had one but I just don't know what it should look like (-:

Comment: If it's not detected in device manager, and you've downloaded drivers for it, it's either not supported or it was an optional extra for the laptop (which hasn't been included).

Comment: Side note: Just to verify, you do have HP SimplePass installed correct?

Comment: @NiallJones: Ah I've downloaded it but either I can't remember my Windows password or the password was set up by the shop I bought the laptop from and I don't know it...

Comment: SimplePass works in coherence with the fingerprint sensor. So try and get into that.

Comment: @NiallJones: OK I've installed it and it mentions the fingerprint scanner and stuff about websites but I don't see any way to set up my fingerprint and the Windows Hello still says there is no compatible scanner. Am I missing something.

Comment: If you cannot remember your Windows password you will have to reset it.  Enabling the built-in Administrator account is the simple solution, to that particular problem.

Comment: @NiallJones: Aha I've been able to verify that [the fingerprint sensor is indeed optional](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04355372#AbT4). Still working on how to tell if my laptop doesn't have it vs having it but not being supported.

Comment: @Ramhound: I remembered my Windows password after a few more tries.